# Explicit Package Error in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I am trying to parse a string and place the parts in an array, and then assign the array components to new variables.  I have done this the exact same way in my code and it works, but now it fails, and I have no clue why.  I think it is something simple, and I am too close to see it.

```
sub timeDiff {
    my ($tday,$tmon,$tyear,$pday,$pmon,$pyear,$tvalue,$pvalue,$reset);
    my (@arrSplitTDate,@arrSplitPDate,$arrSplitTDate,$arrSplitPDate);
    $tvalue = $_[0];
    $pvalue = $_[1];

    print $tvalue;
    print $pvalue;
    @arrSplitTDate = split(/\//, $tvalue);
    $tday = $arrSplitTdate[1];
    $tmon = $arrSplitTdate[0];
    $tyear = $arrSplitTdate[2];

    print $tday . "\n";
    print $tmon . "\n";
    print $tyear . "\n";
}
```

This is the error:

```
Global symbol "@arrSplitTdate" requires explicit package name at LargeLDAPSearch.pl line 173, <DATA> line 558.
```

Anyone see the reason for the error? Thank you.

Comment: FWIW you could skip the (temporarily used) array and simply:  `my ($tmon, $tday, $tyear) = split(/\//, $tvalue);`

Comment: @pilcrow, thank you for that tip.  Cleans up my code immensely.

Comment: Whoa, why the downvotes?  I'm going to offset with a +1 because we know the OP did, in fact, `use strict`, and that's a rare and precious thing in many "basic" perl questions around here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your camelCasing is different between variable declaration and intended use.

`arrSplitTDate` vs. `arrSplitTdate`

Comment: HAHAHA!!!!  Thank you!! I knew it was something so trivial that I just couldn't see because I have been looking at it too long.  Thank you again.

Comment: And this is why we `use strict`.  Because the alternative is "Why is this variable `undef`?  I just assigned to it."

Comment: @cquadrini This_is_also_why_we_use_underscores InSteadoFuglyCameLCasing.

Comment: And, don't forget that you don't need such long variable names in a short lexical scope.